# LinearLayout inside a ScrollView doesn't show

Tags: android, scrollview

Here's my Code

```
mainView = new MainView(this, imageId, text, 3);
mainView.setOnTouchListener(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout mainLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
ScrollView.LayoutParams scrollParams = new 
ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams myViewParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mainLinear.addView(mainView, myViewParams);

scrollView.addView(mainLinear, mainParams);
addContentView(scrollView, scrollParams);
```

Of course it works within `LinearLayout` only. Please tell me how to put it inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: You can try to give the `LinearLayout` a size of `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `MATCH_PARENT`. And (unrelated) why are you doing this in Java rather than XML?

Comment: Are u getting any crash?

Comment: Henry << I'm making a responsive View with Java. it has finished but the scroll. In fact, I can do the scroll by implementing OnTouchListener and then get the 2 Y-axis points ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE to make detect whether user make a drag. But I tried what you've told me. But it didn't work yet!

Comment: lib4 << No crash but no View is appearing whenever I add a ScrollView.

Comment: possible to post MainView class? Or details about it.

Comment: It works only with the LinearLayout and so I don't think it's the problem with the MainView. That MainView is just extends a View. -->public class MainView extends View {} <--

Comment: lib4 << Could you give me your gmail please? I can send MainView to you.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView`'s child should only have height as `WRAP_CONTENT`. If you try the same layout using xml AS will give you a lint warning saying exactly this.

If you need your child view to occupy full height of scroll view when content is less you could use [setFillViewport()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setFillViewport(boolean)).

This should work for you:

```
mainView = new MainView(this, imageId, text, 3);
mainView.setOnTouchListener(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout mainLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
ScrollView.LayoutParams scrollParams = new 
ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams myViewParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mainLinear.addView(mainView, myViewParams);

scrollView.addView(mainLinear, mainParams);
scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
addContentView(scrollView, scrollParams);
```